# Multiple radio button rating in the same form

Tags: php

I tried to search yet i unable to find out what i am looking for.Please help me.I am working on a rating form which using radio button star for rating,I am using while loop of mysqli_fetch_assoc to pull the date from database.As shown below

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orderdetail,orderuser,food WHERE orderuser.CustomerID=orderdetail.CustomerID AND orderuser.OrderID=orderdetail.OrderID AND orderdetail.FoodID=food.FoodID AND orderuser.confirmstatus=1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);


    while($colum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
?>
<img src="../php/<?php echo $colum['Foodphoto'];?>" style="height:150px;width:150px">
<br>
<?php echo $colum['FoodName'];?>
<br>
<div class="stars">
    <form action="">
        <input class="star star-5" id="rate-5[]" type="radio" name="rate[]" />
        <label class="star star-5" for="rate-5[]"></label>
        <input class="star star-4" id="rate-4[]" type="radio" name="rate[]" />
        <label class="star star-4" for="rate-4[]"></label>
        <input class="star star-3" id="rate-3[]" type="radio" name="rate[]" />
        <label class="star star-3" for="rate-3[]"></label>
        <input class="star star-2" id="rate-2[]" type="radio" name="rate[]" />
        <label class="star star-2" for="rate-2[]"></label>
        <input class="star star-1" id="rate-1[]" type="radio" name="rate[]" />
        <label class="star star-1" for="rate-1[]"></label>
    </form>
</div>
<hr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

but the rating for the second result is not working,i find out that is due to the problem of name but i tried to edit it by adding the array still not working. And how could i store them into mysql using php?those tutorial i found only using ajax or jquery i need the ratings submit once the user submitted the form.

Comment: there appears to be no way of relating the form to the record so each form will be identical with multiple identical radio buttons on the page. It might make more sense to see the whole code - especially the sql select query and any associated javascript

Comment: i had edit the post with my select query but i don't think that will matter because what now im facing is for my second $row result when i try to select the radio button rating it will change the first $row result

Comment: Ok - as I said - there is no way to link the form with the record. I shall post a little snippet below

Comment: You can not output the code in a loop like that - IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. With what you have now, not even your labels will be working properly – _all_ labels with `for="rate-5[]"` will activate the _first_ input field with that ID in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is that you cannot relate the form being submitted with the record so any update will not work as expected. One of the simplest ways to accomplis this would be a hidden field with the ID of the record - the ID can then be used in the `update` statement - ie: ( pseudo sql update )

```
update orderdetail set rating=$rate where ID=$id
```

So, add a hidden field per form like this perhaps

```
    while($colum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

<img src='../php/<?php echo $colum['Foodphoto'];?>' style='height:150px;width:150px'>
<br>
<?php echo $colum['FoodName'];?>
<br>

<div class='stars'>
  <form action=''>
    <input class='star star-5' type='radio' id='rate-5' name='rate' />
    <label class='star star-5' for='rate-5'></label>

    <input class='star star-4' type='radio' id='rate-4' name='rate' />
    <label class='star star-4' for='rate-4'></label>

    <input class='star star-3' type='radio' id='rate-3' name='rate' />
    <label class='star star-3' for='rate-3'></label>

    <input class='star star-2' type='radio' id='rate-2' name='rate' />
    <label class='star star-2' for='rate-2'></label>

    <input class='star star-1' type='radio' id='rate-1' name='rate' />
    <label class='star star-1' for='rate-1'></label>
    <!--
        HIDDEN FIELD WITH ID
    -->
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $colum['id'];?>' />
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
```